# C++ combine 3 integers

Tags: c++, arrays, join, integer, concatenation

I need to join 3 integers from some Area
e.q

```
int sens1[]= {11,22,13,66,2};

int x= ?? // and here i need to join sens1[0], sens1[1] and sens1[2] 
          // so the X to be=112213 not like char, like integer value
```

Comment: So you need to do...math? `x + y * 10` type stuff?

Comment: no, it's not a matrix deterinant

Comment: did you try anything?

Comment: @Vakho What has this simple sample tadman gave you to do with matrix determinants?!?

Comment: @Vakho That's a _'Gimme teh codez plz!'_ question, isn't it? You're lucky you've got an answer at all ...

Comment: Seems there is a flaw, that the OP can again gain a +2 by just changing the accepted answer, could some Mod explain about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
std::string s = "";
for(int i=0; i<3; ++i)
    s += std::to_string(sens1[i]);
int n = strtol (s.c_str(), NULL, 10);
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you could use [stringstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/sstream/stringstream/)s for this:

```
int result;
stringstream ss;
ss << sense1[0] << sense1[1] << sense1[2]; //assumes sense1[0,1,2] are all integers
ss >> result; //might need to be careful of integer overflow if it is too long
```

Essentially concatenate them into a string and read it back into an integer.

Comment: Don't forget to turn it back to an integer then ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ that is what the result variable does, does it not?

Comment: Ahh! Sorry didn't spot that first ...

Comment: Someone should step up and write `intstream` that does the concatenation using pure integer math.

Answer (score 0):

You can use sprintf() and atol():

```
char str[255];
long result;
sprintf(str, "%i%i%i", sense1[1], sense1[2], sense1[3]);
result=atol(str);
```

Comment: $str will contain the string consisting of the 3 integers concatenated together.

Comment: sorry, it should be str, not $str.  I edited my answer.  Then, after that, use  i=atoi(str); or i=atol(str); to get it back to an integer.

Comment: That's not a valid c++ symbol!

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ $foo is since decades the standard way to describe variable values... in pseudocode anyway

Comment: @mti2935 Might help if you define `str`.  You likely mean `sprintf()`.  Never heard of `sprint()`.  (Changes to your answer, not the comments please)

Comment: char str[255]; should be sprintf.  edited answer.

Comment: This is valid C, but goes against everything C++ stands for.